# perl with xml : why to I need check if the Attribute is defined, shouldn't $node->attributes already do that?

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to use perl to parse XML and I've run across something that seems odd. When I call $node->attributes() it seems to return an undefined value in some cases. If you look at the line labeled problem, you can see the if I've added. I would have thought that that if the node had no attributes then the foreach wouldn't have had anything to loop on. if I uncomment the if on that line all works. (I know I could put the check outside the loop, but I'm wondering why I need the check at all)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'lib.xml';
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
$parser->keep_blanks(0);

my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($filename);

sub process_node {
    my $level = shift;
    my $node = shift;

    printf ("%*s", $level, "");
    print $node->nodeName;
    print "<", $node->nodeValue,">" if (defined($node->nodeValue));
    print "\n";

    print "attrs:\n";

    foreach ($node->attributes()){
    print $_->name,":",$_->value," " ;# if (defined($_)); ### problem
    }

    print "\n";

    for my $child ($node->childNodes) {
        process_node($level+1, $child);
    }
}

process_node(1, $doc->documentElement);
```

here's the contents of lib.xml:

```
<data size="4">
<stuff src="one" dst="two" />
hmm
</data>
```

and here's the "bad" output:

```
>>> ./xml.pl 
 data
attrs:
size:4 
  stuff
attrs:
src:one dst:two 
  text<
hmm
>
attrs:
Can't call method "name" on an undefined value at ./xml.pl line 26.
```

and the good when I uncomment the if

```
>>> ./xml.pl 
 data
attrs:
size:4 
  stuff
attrs:
src:one dst:two 
  text<
hmm
>
attrs:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of what I believe is a bug in `XML::LibXML::Text::attributes`, which looks like this

```
sub attributes { return undef; }
```

This should be

```
sub attributes { return }
```

which will return `undef` in scalar context and an empty list in list context

You can fix it yourself if you want. In the latest version of the module -- 2.0123 -- it's on line 1789 of `LibXML.pm` in your `XML::LibXML` installation. You can discover where the file is by running

```
perldoc -l XML::LibXML
```

I will raise a bug report with the maintainers

Comment: I'll check this out. Thanks

Comment: @kdubs: I've had a reply already from the library maintainers. The fix, exactly as I wrote it here, has been incorporated into version 2.0124 and will be available on CPAN once it gets uploaded